# How can I fix errors when installing npm version 6.4.1

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, sass, gulp

With an AngularJS application I installed npm --> `npm install`. I get the 6.4.1 version, but when I typed `npm audit` or `npm fix audit` to fix some issues, I have this message showing bellow :

```
λ npm audit
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Missing: gulp-sass@^2.0.4

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\iamari\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-20T10_16_09_010Z-debug.log
```

Then, I tried to fixed with `npm install gulp-sass` or `npm i gulp-sass`. I get `"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",` on package.json file. But I have same errors mentionned previously. 
Any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try removing your `package-lock.json` and then reinstalling `gulp-sass`:

```
rm -f package-lock.json
npm i gulp-sass
```

It looks like you may have a lockfile conflict.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot it works :) I have the diagnostic of vulnerabilities `found 78 vulnerabilities (35 low, 12 moderate, 30 high, 1 critical) in 16201 scanned packages
  75 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
  3 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.`